Plugins not installing when doing initial setup locally
My team is running Craft CMS on Docker. On starting up it pulls a backup of the production DB, applies the Craft config and copies across the data from the backup. All the data is there (entries, assets, etc.) except for plugins.
Other team members are able to get this working fine, following the exact same steps as I have. They build and run and all the DB data and plugins are active. For me, the data is there but the plugins are not. We have checked our local .sql copies of the database and they appear to match, with the same file size.
I’ve tried several things including running composer install, rebuilding the docker container numerous times and installing one-off plugins through Admin to try and get it to trigger a refresh and pick up on the other plugins. Running Craft 5.4.8, PHP 8.3.6 and PostgreSQL 14.13. Docker version is 4.36.0 and on a MacBook Pro M4 Pro on 15.2 Sequoia.
Does anyone have any ideas what could be happening or suggestions of what to try next?
Included screenshot of system report from Admin/Utilities:


Welcome to Craft SE! For a troubleshooting question like this one, I'd actually recommend asking in the Craft Discord instead. An issue like this may require some back-and-forth questioning and testing to find a resolution.
